# File accessible only by application

Tags: php, permissions

This might be silly question, but Im not exactly sure how to look it up. I have a config.xml file which is holding some information that should not be public, so if I go to www.domain.com/config.xml then this file should be protected however my web application needs to read from this file.

I have tried setting permissions to this file (on hosting) to "000" (linux based) but then my scripts cannot read the file. However when I set it to "600" then everybody can access this file.

Can you point me the right direction? I only need this file to be hidden to public users, but visible and accessible by my php scripts.

Comment: You can use .htaccess to prevent people from opening files directly. You can do that for every file, or for all xml etc.

Comment: this seems reasonable, can I apply this on all files in particular folder?

Comment: Yes, or to a type of files, or miltiple files. Or reversed, only the list you agree too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put XML file outside of your public folder, it will still be accessible for your application, but not to the outside world.

Ex. If your public directory is **/var/www/site/public_html** put your XML file to the **/var/www/site/**

**EDIT1:**
If above does not suit your needs you can use htaccess:

```
<Files "config.xml">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

**EDIT2:** Since you can't use any of above, let's try 3rd option:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(xml)$    -   [F,NC]
```

[Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/access.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this would surely work, but I may need to put this on several hosting and Im not sure if each and everyone of them would have an "outside" folder available for me.

Comment: Edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Thank you, however it unfortunately does not work. I think it might be to apache settings. I found that you need to use "AllowOverride All" in apache config, do you think this could be the issue? Problem is that I cannot access such file on the hosting.

Comment: ^^yes that is a problem.

Comment: As it comes I manage to get it working afterall :) Thank you very much and if I can I would ask one last question. Is this a standard way of hiding files? I mean I will probably use this on a whole directory, but Im a little worried that not all hostings will support this.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to do it. Well you have 3 ways now as I posted. If you ask me I would try them in order they are posted.

Comment: And Im very glad you helped me with this. I wasnt quite sure what to search for and this helped me a lot, thank you very much :-)